# how to clear the effect of system wide bashrc

Tags: bashrc

At my company there are system-wide bashrc files like `/etc/bashrc` and so on.

Inside, they source more and more files. It's very confusing (I noticed my "ls" is aliased with a bunch of flags to ls that I don't want).

I want to for my `~/.bashrc` clear the effects of all bashrcs.

Is there something like that in bash? Just to clear all aliases, functions, etc, defined in system-wide files.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add this line to your `~/.bashrc` :

```
unalias -a
```

As far as I know, there is no equivalent for clearing all functions. You can, however, clear them one by one using

```
unset -f function_name
```

The following two bash options are also relevant:

```
  --rcfile file
          Execute  commands  from file instead of the system wide
          initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and  the  standard
          personal  initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is
          interactive (see INVOCATION below).

  --norc Do  not read and execute the system wide initialization
          file /etc/bash.bashrc and the  personal  initialization
          file  ~/.bashrc  if  the  shell  is  interactive.  This
          option is on by default if the shell is invoked as sh.
```

So, you could set `bash` to be an alias for `bash --norc`:

```
    alias bash='/bin/bash --norc'
```

That way, every time you manually launch `bash` a new shell will be started with no initialization files. You would then need to manually source your `.bashrc`.

I thought you could combine the `--norc` and `--rcfile` options to read your `~/.bashrc` only but could not get it to work.